# Java - Change Attribute of Subclass Object

Tags: java

I have the following java superclass with constructor and getters and setters for each attribute:

```
public  class vehicle {
     int vehicleId;

public vehicle(int vehicleId) {
        super();
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;

    }

     public int getVehicleId() {
    return vehicleId;
}

public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
    this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
}
```

And a car subclass that extends the vehicle super class and has a few unique attributes:

```
public class car extends vehicle{

private String wheels;

//constructor
    public car( int vehicleId, String wheels) {
        super(vehicleId);
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }

//getters and setters 

public int getWheels() {
    return wheels;
}

public void setWheels(int wheels) {
    this.wheels = wheels;
}
```

I create a new linked list of vehicle objects and add a new car object to it:

```
LinkedList<vehicle> gbm = new LinkedList<vehicle>();
car car = new car(0, "");
car.setVehicleId(1);
car.setWheels("alloy");
gbm.add(car);
```

I can change any of the attributes that belong to the vehicle super class with a function like this:

```
public static void editVehicleId(int vid, int vehicleId) {

        for (vehicle obj : gbm) {
            if (obj.vehicleId == vid) {
                obj.setVehicleId(vehicleId);

            } else {
                System.out.println("No matching vehicle Id found - please check input");
            }
        }

    }
```

But when I try to create a similar function to change one of the subclass attributes, i get this error: "the method setWheels(int) is undefined for the type vehicle".

```
public static void editWheels(int vid, int wheels) {

        for (vehicle obj : gbm) {
            if (obj.vehicleId == vid) { 
                obj.setWheels(wheels);

            } else {
                System.out.println("No matching vehicle Id found - please check input");
            }
        }

    }
```

Can somebody tell me how to edit one of the subclass specific attributes?

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, strip down your code to the absolute minimum needed to show your issue. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this is polymorphism , you can use car instance if you want to access property belongs to car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop variable is a vehicle type. Since this is a method for the car class, make it a car object:

```
for (vehicle obj : gbm) {
    if (obj.vehicleId == vid) {
        if (obj instanceof car) {
            ((car)obj).setWheels(wheels);
        }
    }
    ... rest of loop ...
}
```

Comment: "type mismatch: cannot convert from element type vehicle to car"

Comment: Please see my edit. Actually, the loop variable should still be vehicle since that is the wrapped type of the ArrayList gmb. But you can check if the obj is a car with instanceof and if so, cast it to type car before calling setWheels

Comment: I suppose one solution would be to use a different linked list for each different type of vehicle instead of all together in one.

Comment: True, but you may want to just look through all vehicles and only care about the subclass sometimes. It depends on what you want to do with the list.